# Facebook infinite redirect loop during authentication

Tags: facebook

I am getting an infinite loop in the URL redirect after a user either logs in or is already logged in. The page redirects to the login page if the user is not logged in as expected , but goes in the loop as soon as he enters the credentials.

Following is the code:

```
<?php

include_once ('facebook.php');
  $api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $secret  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  global $facebook;
  $facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);
$facebook->require_frame();
$uid = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'email,status_update,offline_access');
$facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission("offline_access",$uid);
#echo $uid;
 #   $facebook->api_client->users_setStatus("hello",$uid);
  #   echo "<p>Your status has been updated</p>";
 ?>
```

Interestingly this code was working before, but suddenly started giving me an infinite loop problem. There have been couple of discussion on facebook forum about this but no indication that is a bug or what is the workaround .

Any help would be highly appreciateed.

Thanks

Comment: Had a similar issue when I started coding for fb, at that point, I was tring to access the application directly from my server instead of going to the application using facebook(using the fb uri -- the proper way to access your application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the code to direct to login only if the user is not logged in else do not do that. This worked for me! .. Hope it helps.

```
$is_tab = isset($_POST['fb_sig_in_profile_tab']);
if( !$is_tab ){
    $uid = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'email,status_update                                              ,offline_access');
}
else{
    $uid = $facebook->get_profile_user();
}
```